# From a guessing game in python, I can't get myself to get the correct one

Tags: python

This is my code:

```html
from sys import exit
import random
number = random.randint(1, 10)
count = 0

def guess():
    
    print ("Input a number 1 - 10")
    guess = input()

    if guess == "I give up":
        print ("The correct number was", number,"!")
        print ("You tried", count, "times before giving up!")
        exit(0)
    else:
        if guess == (number):
            print ("CORRECT!")
            print (count, "failed attempts.")
            exit(0)
        else:
            print ("WRONG!")
            print ("Try again!")
            global count
            count += 1
    
while True:
    guess()
```

If I run this, I can keep guessing but never get the correct number. I said I gave up, and it gave me the correct number. But I already guessed that number, so I don't know what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking the input as a string rather than an integer. Thus, you may be comparing `"5"` to `5`, which is false. Instead, call `if int(guess) == (number)`

Comment: Glad to be of help